# Light adaption of pupil. When is a size adaption normal?

Tags: eye, neurology, reflex-impulse

If an eye gets lighted with a flashlight or other light sources the pupils will decrease their width. This pupillary response is a typical indicator in diagnostics. Is there any specific value which can be used as threshold to decide whether the test of pupillary response is passed or not?

EDIT:
I read much about the pupillary response. There is much literature about how to do the checks and what are possible diagnoses but I was not able to find a specific value to decide whether the test of pupillary response is passed or not. I also asked medical staff and they told me you will see it and its about experience.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks for your response. I added my research results

Comment: In your research you surely came across pupil size charts with specific values. But that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for, so now it's unclear to me what you're looking for. Are you looking for a measure of speed of pupillary response or something else?

Comment: @CareyGregory Thats right. I am looking for relative values which explain how much the pupil size should decrease if the eye gets lighted. Something like the pupils will decrease by 20%. I did not found information like this, so I think there isnt any defined threshold. But maybe someone knows better

Comment: It would help if you clarified that in your question.